# Dickey Fuller and deterministic regressors

Tags: econometrics, stata, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

Can somebody help me with how I can determine what deterministic regressors(trend, drift and intercept) I shall include in the Dickey Fuller test.
A Stata help file outlines four cases:

1   Random walk without drift   α(Intercept)=0,θ(trend)=0
2   Random walk without drift   α=0,
3   Random walk with drift  θ=0
4   Random walk with  drift or without drift    No deterministic regressor

I have estimated all of them but how do I know which result to take. So far I cannot reject the Null for all of them except if a drift term is included.

Comment: This is a general and still persisting problem in econometrics/statistics. In general you - as an applied person - "must" have some knowledge about the trending behavior of your data. Though there are some ways out of this situation when it come to trends... see [this](https://www.nottingham.ac.uk/research/groups/grangercentre/documents/07-03.pdf) for example.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate as it is a frequently encountered issue; you might try looking it up. Probably you will find a good answer there, too.